# Looking for a component that lets me choose where to draw power from

Tags: power-supply, power, switches, converter

I would like to have a switch or box that allows me to plug a battery and wall power into the box, and then has a switch that chooses which power to use for the output.

The ideal inputs of the box are a 12v battery and 120v AC wall plug, and the ideal output is 12V DC out.

What is the electrical component/design that allows me to do this? Commercially available is an option!

Comment: At what current?

Comment: Currents will be less than 5A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 12V wall wart (AC-to-DC converter) and a SPDT switch.

Comment: Or 5A 12V SPDT relay to battery charger to battery with wallwart with NC to battery and Vmax protection

Comment: That will work, but I was hoping for a commercially available product that did it all

Comment: @JoeS, requests for product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Yea I have noticed a lot of rules are unfriendly towards applications of electrical engineering.

Comment: @JoeS The idea of Stack Exchange is to build up a database of questions and answers to use as a reference for the future. Helping people right now is almost a side effect. Because of this, product reconditions are rejected as going stale as time progresses. Like it or not, that’s how it’s set up.